# Get accumulated sum per hour

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, accumulate

I have a simple counter table:

```
date                   action      type
2017-04-25 11:41:38    +1          type_1
2017-04-25 11:66:22    +1          type_2
2017-04-25 12:41:32    -1          type_1
2017-04-25 12:55:38    +1          type_3
2017-04-25 13:02:11    -1          type_1
```

I want to do a graph with accumulated visits pr hour pr type and skip those with 0. So that I get a graph with every hour on the x-axis and visits on the y-axis. Then four accumulated graphs, one per type and one total.

So far I got the following statement which just gives me the sum pr hour without the types. I need a bit of help to evolve this into the described above.

```
SELECT    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W %k:00') as weekday, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y %k:00') as full_date, SUM(action) as total
FROM      counter
GROUP BY  HOUR(date)
```

Desired result:

```
date                 total         type
2017-04-25 11:00     3             type_1
2017-04-25 11:00     5             type_2
2017-04-25 11:00     8             type_3
2017-04-25 11:00     16            total
2017-04-25 12:00     6             type_1
2017-04-25 12:00     9             type_2
2017-04-25 12:00     14            type_3
2017-04-25 12:00     29            total
```

I think this will provide me with the data to do the desired graphs

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Provide desired results as a table in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, summarize the data by hour:

```
select date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H') as yyyymmddhh, type, sum(action) as cnt
from counter
group by yyyymmddhh, type;
```

Next, you can use variables to get the cumulative values:

```
select yyyymmddhh, type, cnt,
       (@cs := if(@t = type, @cs + cnt,
                  if(@t := type, cnt, cnt)
                 )
       ) as cumulative_cnt
from (select date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H') as yyyymmddhh, type, sum(action) as cnt
      from counter
      group by yyyymmddhh, type
     ) c cross join
     (select @t := '', @cs := 0) params
order by type, yyyymmddhh;
```

If you need the result in a different order, then use this as a subquery and put the `order by` in the outer query.